# O que "\" quer dizer no cabeçalho de C++?

Tags: c, c++, macro, preprocessador

Eu estava olhando no cabeçalho da MFC e não sei o que o caractere "\" quer dizer neste contexto:

```
#define BEGIN_MESSAGE_MAP(theClass, baseClass) \
PTM_WARNING_DISABLE \
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Quando você usa `#define` ele pressupõe que o código terá apenas uma linha ali, ao contrário do código normal, então as diretivas de pré-processamento não terminam a linha com um `;`, a linha termina quando há uma quebra de linha.

E se você precisa fazer um código ali que exige várias linhas? Você deve indicar que a linha de baixo é continuação daquele `#define` e não uma nova linha. Neste contexto o caractere `\` é usado para informar isto ao pré-processador.

Então neste exemplo a linha de baixo faz parte deste mesmo `#define` e certamente existe mais uma linha abaixo desta que também faz parte deste mesmo `#define`, já que a segunda linha também tem um indicador de continuidade.

Como todos os recursos usados no pré-processador este precisa ser usado com cuidado porque é fácil achar que está fazendo uma coisa e ter resultado diferente do esperado.

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/C/Conceptual.md).

Comment: Vlw, eu estava com dificuldade de achar essa resposta

Comment: Sei que o AP é bem específico sobre o *contexto*, mas acho que convém editar a resposta pra melhorá-la no sentido de que esse caractere não vale apenas para uso no `#define`. Ele pode ser muito útil também para definir longas strings, por exemplo. :)

Comment: @LuizVieira Neste caso vou deixar só seu comentário mesmo, vou mudar só pra clarificar o contexto. Obrigado.